# Keras transpose

Tags: keras

Using Keras 2 with TensorFlow backend

I need to transpose an output of a Convolutional2D before feeding it to concat

The output of Conv2D is `(Conv2D) (None, 30, 40, 6)`

It needs to be `(None, 6, 30, 40)`

I tried `transpose` but they are giving a tensor, it needs to be a layer output.

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras.layers import Permute 
output = Permute(dims=(2,1,3))(output)
```

If the dimensions of the tensor/layer is NWHC then its represented by `0,1,2,3`

If you wanted to transpose h & w the code is as above.